# how to stop a picture in a picture box from randomizing again after clicking a button again?

Tags: c#

i am working on a blackjack assignment for college. i have three picture boxes with the cards in them. i have a draw button that draws up to three cards. but every time i press the button the card randomizes again. i have it set up so that it draws one card at a time. i click for one card but when i click for the second card the first card randomizes again and same for the second and third.

code:

```
int count = 0;

    private void BtnDraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Card3;
        int Card4;
        int Card5;


        Random randomizer = new Random();

        //get random numbers
        Card3 = randomizer.Next(1, 53);
        Card4 = randomizer.Next(1, 53);
        Card5 = randomizer.Next(1, 53);

        // Display the card
        PicCard3.Image = imageList1.Images[Card3];
        PicCard4.Image = imageList1.Images[Card4];
        PicCard5.Image = imageList1.Images[Card5];
```

here is the code for show the cards one at a time:

```
if (count == 0)
        {
            //Make PictureBox1 visible
            PicCard3.Visible = true;
            count++;


        }
        else if (count == 1)
        {
            //Make PictureBox visible
            PicCard4.Visible = true;
            count++;



        }
        else if (count == 2)
        {
            //Make PictureBox3 visible
            PicCard5.Visible = true;
            count++;
        }
        else if (count == 3)
        {
            //Hide all PictureBoxes again
            PicCard3.Visible = false;
            PicCard4.Visible = false;
            PicCard5.Visible = false;
            count = 0;
        }
```

Comment: while i hesitate to update homework code for specifics...the variables randomize again because its in the button click method to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need few logic changes:

- Whole operations should be based on value of `count`
- No need for separate Random numbers
- randomizer should not be a local variable

In short your code should be something like this:

```
Random randomizer = new Random();
int count = 0;
private void BtnDraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int randomCardIndex = randomizer.Next(0,53);
    if (count == 0)
    {
        PicCard3.Image = imageList1.Images[randomCardIndex];
        PicCard3.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (count == 1)
    {
        PicCard4.Image = imageList1.Images[randomCardIndex];
        PicCard4.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (count == 2)
    {
        PicCard5.Image = imageList1.Images[randomCardIndex];
        PicCard5.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (count == 3)
    {
        PicCard3.Visible = false;
        PicCard4.Visible = false;
        PicCard5.Visible = false;
        count = -1;
    }
    count++;
}
```

Please note :

If you need to show only one card at a time, make all other card's `.Visible = false;` in matching conditions

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the randomizer when the form is loaded rather than when the buttons are clicked.

Or alternatively

```
if(count == 0) {

// Do randomizer for each card

}
```

is another way of doing this though not as clean